# jquery checking if element isnt X or if parent of element isnt X - can it be done simpler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, coffeescript

Here is my coffeescript where I track all body clicks:

```
 $('body').on 'click', (e) ->
        if  not $(e.target).hasClass('notification') and $(e.target).parents('td.notification').length != 1
            $('a.notification-link').popover('hide')
```

according to js2coffe it should be:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('notification') && $(e.target).parents('td.notification').length !== 1) {
    return $('a.notification-link').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

Can I do it somehow simpler than this checks?

Comment: i stopped to read when i saw the word coffeescript. but besides that, i dont think you can do it using less checks

Comment: `$(e.target).closest('.notification').length === 0`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon if you post it as the answe I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the jQuery doc for [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) :

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

So simply checking for the class `notification` will work :

```
if($(e.target).closest('.notification').length === 0)...
```